# removing a word from a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I'm to put a image to my sdl application and for that I need to know the path for it. It works when I put the full path into a `IMG_Load()` function. When I try to use the windows.h function `GetModuleFileName()` and combine that with another array of chars I get:

> C:\Users\micro 
>   capacitor\source\repos\FlatApoc\x64\Debug\FlatApoc.exe/Images/Play1.png

The problem i am trying to fix is to get rid of

> FlatApoc.exe

from the char array. I already know that the

> FlatApoc.exe

comes from `GetModuleFileName()`. The solution to fix this problem would just be to remove FlatApoc.exe from the char array but I am pretty new to c++ and I don't know how to do such a function.

The code I have is:

```
char path[MAX_PATH]; // The path of the executable
GetModuleFileName(NULL, path, sizeof(path)); // Get the path
char pathbuff[256]; // Buffer for the png file
strncpy_s(pathbuff, path, sizeof(pathbuff));
strncat_s(pathbuff, "/Images/Play1.png", sizeof(pathbuff));
Button_Play1 = IMG_Load(pathbuff);
```

Comment: Using `std::string` and maybe `std::regex` would make this way easier.

Comment: Also [`boost filesystem`](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.filesystem-paths) or the latest standard additions for [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem) would make that easy as snipping your fingers. (not to mention some basic WinAPI functions you could use to extract the directory part of a full file path)

Comment: Why are you writing C but tagging the question C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ way.  Note how much more natural it looks:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    char path [MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName (NULL, path, sizeof (path));
    std::string s = path;
    auto n = s.rfind ('\\');
    s.erase (n);
    s += "/Images/Play1.png";
    std::cout << s;
}
```

[Live demo](https://rextester.com/EDUH73439)

Answer (score 0):

Nvm. I fixed it now but I am leaving the code here:

```
char path[MAX_PATH]; // The path of the executable
GetModuleFileName(NULL, path, sizeof(path)); // Get the path
char search[] = "\\FlatApoc.exe"; // The programs name
char *ptr = strstr(path, search);
*ptr = NULL;

char pathbuff[256]; // Buffer for the png file
strncpy_s(pathbuff, path, sizeof(pathbuff));
strncat_s(pathbuff, "/Images/Play1.png", sizeof(pathbuff)); // "/Images/Play1.png" was the link from the executables folder
Button_Play1 = IMG_Load(pathbuff); // Load image
```